# How to edit MySQL event with invalid name?

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I have an event named nolin_kuota_prioritas_JKT-TGS-pagi. I wanted to disable it, but MySQL Workbench said `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-TGS-pagi' at line 1`

I got same error for command `show create event nolin_kuota_prioritas_JKT-TGS-pagi` or `alter event nolin_kuota_prioritas_JKT-TGS-pagi disable`.

I am using MySQL Workbench 8.0.20 build 16114288 CE. And while writing this I update to 8.0.21, and still get the same error.

How can I disable this event?

Thank you.

Comment: Enclose event name in backticks.

Comment: back-ticks is (or are?) the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Why is it marked as duplicate question? If I know the answer would be back-ticks, I wouldn't asked.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled and also review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html#:~:text=An%20identifier%20may%20be%20quoted,it%20need%20not%20be%20quoted.)